# Create a statitics table for calls made with Doctrine

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I am trying to set a Eoctrine table, like this:

```
Provider Caller CallsRequested CallsFailed
X          A       20              1
Y          B       15              0
X          B       5               0
```

And so on. I am currently doing like this:

```
$repository = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Stats::Class);



     $stats = $repository->findBy(
      array('provider' => $provider, 'CallCenter'=> $callCenterContact));   //returns NULL


        if (!$stats) {
            $stats = new stats;
            $stats->setProvider($provider);
            $stats->setCallCenter($callCenterContact);
            $stats->setCalls_Requested(1);

            $this->entityManager->persist($stats);
            $this->entityManager->flush();

          }
          else{
            $count=$stats->getCalls_Requested();
            $stats->setCalls_Requested($count+1);
            $id =  $stats->getId();      
            $stats->setId($id);
            $this->entityManager->persist($stats); 
             $this->entityManager->flush();
          }
```

But I am getting two problems:

- it creates me a row for each Call Request, with a new id,
- it does not increment the number of calls.

How can I do what I want?

Answer (score 0):

in else try this

```
        else{
            $count=$stats->getCalls_Requested();
            $stats->setCalls_Requested($count+1);
            $this->entityManager->merge($stats); 
             $this->entityManager->flush();
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had two problems, one was because the size of one of my colums was to short, so the field in the DB and the one I was triying to insert was diferent. The second was that my $stats was an array, so i could not manipulate him. 
I did the following for future reference:

```
 $repository = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Stats::Class);

    $stats = $repository->findBy(
  array('provider' => $provider, 'CallCenter'=>$callCenterContact));   


    if (!$stats) {
        $stats = new stats;
        $stats->setProvider($provider);
        $stats->setCallCenter($callCenterContact);
        $stats->setCalls_Requested(1);

        $this->entityManager->persist($stats);
        $this->entityManager->flush();

      }
      else{
        $stats[0]->setCalls_Requested($stats[0]->getCalls_Requested()+1);

        $this->entityManager->persist($stats[0]); 
         $this->entityManager->flush();
      }
```